# how do I set a column to be the default sort column with Telerik RadGridView in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, sorting, telerik, default, radgridview

I have a RadGridView control in a  silverlight project and would like to have the grid come up sorted by the name column. I tried placing the attribute SortingState="Ascending" on the column definition for the name. I do not see any other attributes that might accomplish this. Does anyone know how to make this happen?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will want to add a SortDescriptor to the grid

```
<telerik:RadGridView.SortDescriptors>
    <telerik:SortDescriptor Member="Name" SortDirection="Ascending" />
</telerik:RadGridView.SortDescriptors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, what about the 'ColumnSortDescriptor'?

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GridView/Sorting

There are examples and code there.